# how to install scrapy witn py36 in win10

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Recently we want to rewrite our project with python3(now it was py2.7).We mainly use scrapy to grab data from website,but I can't install scrapy in py36 now.

```
  Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 24: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "e:\python_envs\crawler36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

Seems the problem is twisted.I tried to install twisted also got the same exception.Others told me to install twisted.whl,but I can't find this file in internet.
Please help.

Comment: How did you create your virtualenvironment?

Comment: On Windows, Scrapy docs [recommend using Anaconda/Miniconda](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows) with `conda-forge` channel.

Comment: thanks for kindly response.now it is ok,I install twisted by whl file.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Installation Requirements](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/INSTALL.rst) of Twisted on GitHub,
it looks like it is not yet compatible with Python 3.6:

> To install Twisted, you need:
>
> Python 2.7 (full functionality) or 3.3/3.4/3.5 (subset of functionality).

Indeed, in the Python 3.6 [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html), you can see that:

> PEP 528 and PEP 529, Windows filesystem and console encoding changed to UTF-8.

This affects the value returned by `sys.__stdout__.encoding`, which causes the `UnicodeDecodeError` you see in the stack trace.

So I would suggest you to keep using Python 3.5 until Twisted updates to support Python 3.6. If you really cannot, as a last resort try setting up your project in a non-Windows environment (e.g. a virtual machine), or hack around this issue by setting the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to whatever `sys.__stdout__.encoding` used to return before the upgrade to 3.6. But it has downsides, it may not work, and there might be other incompatibilities down the road anyway.

Comment: thanks for kindly response.now it is ok,I install twisted by whl file.